# How to save CSV logs in Azure AppendBlob

Tags: c#-4.0, azure-blob-storage, linqtocsv

How to store csv logs to Azure AppendBlob without affecting any perfomance?

My code to write csv to memory stream:

```
public static byte[] WriteCsvWithHeaderToMemory<T>(IEnumerable<T> records) where T : class
{
    var outputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
    {
        SeparatorChar = ',',
        EnforceCsvColumnAttribute = true,
    };

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
        {
            var context = new CsvContext();
            context.Write(records, streamWriter, outputFileDescription);
        }
        return memoryStream.ToArray();                
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public async Task WriteToAudit<T>(T logData)
{
    var list = new List<T> {logData};

    var appendBlob = GetAppendBlobReference();
    appendBlob.FetchAttributes();

    var auditDataBytes = WriteCsvWithHeaderToMemory(list,appendBlob.Properties.Length);

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(auditDataBytes))
    {
        await appendBlob.AppendBlockAsync(stream).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

public static byte[] WriteCsvWithHeaderToMemory<T>(IEnumerable<T> records, long blobSize) where T : class
{
    var outputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
    {
        SeparatorChar = ',',
        EnforceCsvColumnAttribute = true,
        FirstLineHasColumnNames = blobSize <= 0 
    };

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
        {
            var context = new CsvContext();
            context.Write(records, streamWriter, outputFileDescription);
        }
        return memoryStream.ToArray();                
    }
}
```